# Ajax request after sometime freeze browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have made admin panel where setup notification alerts using ajax. It is working fine, but after few minutes than it starts to freeze the browser. Any idea what I am doing wrong, as it is my first Ajax project.

Following are codes which I am using, I used setInterval in a function which is called by body onload event.

```
<html>    
    <body onload="process()">
        <-- Some notification divs to be replaced by javascript -->
    </body>
<html>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function process() {
    setInterval('process()', 10000);
    if (xmlHttp) {  
       try {
           xmlHttp.open("GET", "response.json", true);
           xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
           xmlHttp.send(null);
       } catch (e) {
           console.log("Can't connect to server:\n" + e.toString())
       };
    }
}

            function handleRequestStateChange() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                    {
                        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                            try {

                                handleServerResponse();

                            } catch (e) {}

                        } else {
                            console.log("There was a problem retrieving the data:\n" + xmlHttp.statusText);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            function handleServerResponse() {

                responseJson = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.newbooking.length; i++) {

                    //   html += "<li><a href='admin_user.php?id=" +  + "'><div class='desc'>" + responseJson.users[i].first_name + ", " +responseJson.users[i].last_name + " joined</div></a></li>";

                    bookinghtml += "<li><a href='makeinvoice.php?bookingid=" + responseJson.newbooking[i].booking_id + "'><span class='subject'><span class='from'>" + responseJson.newbooking[i].company_name + " </span><span class='time'> " + responseJson.newbooking[i].user_name + " </span></span>";
                    bookinghtml += "<span class='message'> from " + responseJson.newbooking[i].start_date + ", " + responseJson.newbooking[i].batches + "  " + responseJson.newbooking[i].campaign + "</span></a></li>";
                }



                myDiv = document.getElementById("bookinginfo");
                myDiv.innerHTML = bookinghtml;


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you make a request, you tell it to make a request every 10 seconds.

1. So onload, you make a request and start a timer.
2. 10 seconds later you make another request and start another timer.
3. 10 seconds later you make two requests, each of which starts another timer.
4. 10 seconds later you make four requests, each of which starts another timer.

and so on.

It starts freezing, because it eventually is making trying to make requests faster then the computer can handle.

Use `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`.

(Also, you should pass a function, not a string: `setTimeout(process, 10000)`);

Comment: Thanks,issue resolved btw what is best way to call Ajax on time interval, and is my javascript ok to change divs?